# Autosys job to start after another job with any status

Tags: autosys

I need to run job after another job with whatever status the previous job finished.

So far I use

```
condition: success(x) or failure(x)
```

can it be written for any status?

I dont know the exact version of the autosys. But not the very latest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

condition: done(x)